# Update promise value with fetch http response info

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I retrieve json data from my server in this way:

```
const stream = Observable.fromPromise(fetch('http://...')).flatMap(response => response.json())
```

And now I would like to merge some http response properties into the returned value.

The code below doesn't work actually. Properties seem to be merge into the promise itself instead of its value...

```
const stream = Observable.fromPromise(fetch('http://...')).flatMap(response => {
  const data = response.json()
  return {
    ...data,
    responseStatus: {
      code: response.code,
      text: response.text,
    }
  }
)
```

There is something I don't understand..

Comment: `.json()` returns a promise.

Comment: Thanks ! So I created a new observable from `.json()` and merged properties with the map operator. It works, but I don't know if it's the best solution, as often with rx for a beginner !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.json()` return a promise ! (thanks @Felix-Kling for the tip)

```
const stream = Observable.fromPromise(fetch('http://...')).flatMap(response =>
  Observable.from(response.json()).map(data => ({
    ...data,
    responseStatus: {
      code: response.status,
      text: response.statusText,
    },
  }))
)
```

Please add a comment if you have a better/other answer

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps you, flatMap will flatten the promise to the result value, in the next operator you will receive a tuple with resp and the json

```
Observable
  .fromPromise(fetch('yourUrl'))
  .flatMap(resp => resp.json()()
  .map(data => ({
    ...data,
    responseStatus: {
      code: data.code,
      text: data.text,
    }
  }))
```

Comment: Sorry but your answer is wrong. Second map fn argument is the index. After correction of this, and the weird ":any", it produce an exception.

Comment: @TeChn4K i was using typescript sorry, i updated the the reply

Comment: There is still a problem : response status is not available in map function because flatMap return response value...